# Swift: Value of type 'FileHandle' has no member when referencing custom function nested inside subclass of FileHandle but extension works fine

Tags: swift

With Swift 5 and Xcode 12.5.1, I created a subclass of FileHandle named CSVFile and added three functions to the subclass.  Two of those functions are parameterless, but the third contains multiple parameters.  I can call the two parameterless functions from another module, but when I try to call the third one which has parameters, I get:

Value of type 'FileHandle' has no member 'writeSamples'

When I move writeSamples into an extension of FileHandle, then the error goes away.

Here's my non-working code:

```
class CSVFile: FileHandle {
    var fileName: String = ""
    convenience init(fileName: String) {
        self.init()
        self.fileName = fileName
    }
    
    func uniqueSuffix() -> String {
        let now = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        return String(Int(now))
    }
    
    func openFile() -> FileHandle {
        let suffix = uniqueSuffix()
        let docDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let csvURL = docDir.appendingPathComponent(fileName+"_"+suffix).appendingPathExtension("csv")
        var fileHandle: FileHandle
        do {
            FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: csvURL.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
            fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: csvURL)
            print("opened file: \(csvURL.path)")
        } catch {
            print("Cannot open \(csvURL)\nError: \(error)")
            exit(1)
        }
        return fileHandle
    }
    
    func writeSamples(pkgIDs: [Double], timestamps: [Double], markers: [Double], samples: [[Double]]) {
        for iSample in 0..<timestamps.count {
            let pkgID = String(format: "%d", Int(pkgIDs[iSample]))
            let tStamp = String(format: "%.6f", timestamps[iSample])
            let marker = String(format: "%d", Int(markers[iSample]))
            var sampleString = pkgID + "," + tStamp + "," + marker
            for iChannel in 0..<samples.count {
                sampleString += "," + String(format: "%.5f", samples[iChannel][iSample]/24.0)
            }
            sampleString += "\n"
            self.write(Data(sampleString.utf8))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted does compile. What do you mean by "non-working"?

Comment: "Value of type 'FileHandle' has no member 'writeSamples'" Because it's not in FileHandle. It's in a subclass, CSVFile. But your extension injects it directly into FileHandle. Do you understand what a subclass is?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your questions.  The code above is non-working because when I try to call writeSamples from another module, I get the error mentioned above.  To get it to compile perhaps you can add "Import Foundation" to the top of it.  My mistake for leaving that out.

Comment: Hi Matt.  Yes I think I know what a subclass is.  Why does writeSamples need to be in an extension, but the other two functions do not?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: the openFile function returns a FileHandle, not a CSVFile.  So when I try to call writeSamples on an object returned by openFile, it does not have a member named writeSamples.

If I change openFile to the following, then I can call writeSamples without it being in an extension:

```
    func openFile() -> CSVFile {
        let suffix = uniqueSuffix()
        let docDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let csvURL = docDir.appendingPathComponent(fileName+"_"+suffix).appendingPathExtension("csv")
        var fileHandle: CSVFile
        do {
            FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: csvURL.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
            fileHandle = try CSVFile(forWritingTo: csvURL)
            print("opened file: \(csvURL.path)")
        } catch {
            print("Cannot open \(csvURL)\nError: \(error)")
            exit(1)
        }
        return fileHandle
    }
```

Thanks Matt for asking that leading question.  It gave me the clue I needed to figure out the answer for myself.